# jQuery select element id from String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, So I am a little noob here and I think that my terminology might be wrong so please feel free to correct me (I need to learn).

I want to create a better user experience on an FAQ page and ask the user if the question was helpful. If not provide an Alternative. I am trying to add a class to a div that contains the question.

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/u596vwwn/

Here is the jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.faq-question').click(function() {
      var question = $(this).attr('href');
      question = question.replace('#', '');
      var questionData = document.getElementById(question).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(question).innerHTML = questionData + '<div class="row further-help">Did this answer your question? <span id="further-help-yes">Yes</span> | <span id="further-help-no">No</span></div>';
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#further-help-yes', function() {
      $(this).parent('.further-help').fadeOut();

    });

    $('body').on('click', '#further-help-no', function() {
      $(this).parent('.further-help').html('Please contact us <a href="#">here</a>.');

    });
  });
```

What I want, when the user clicks the link in the fiddle. The div container the question will then have a class added so that I can style it.

I tried getting the element like so:

```
 var questionContainer = document.getElementById(question);
```

and then add a class like so:

```
questionContainer.addClass('selected-faq');
```

but it is not adding it.

Comment: Tip: Use either `jQuery` or `Vanilla Javascript`. You don't need to mix them up here.

Comment: ***Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined***. Always check your console.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `questionContainer` is not a jQuery element, but was selected with plain JS (`getElementById`). Try this:

```
var $questionContainer = $(question);
$questionContainer.addClass('selected-faq');
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The problem was that the fiddle did not include jquery.

Comment: That might be, but that doesn't mean the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @TravisJ: Given that Fabian is addressing the code that was actually included in the question, I'd say it's correct. Extra information posted on some other site is irrelevant, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have confused yourself by switching between jQuery and plain Javascript. Just stick to jQuery to keep it simple.

```
$('.faq-question').click(function() {
  var question = $($(this).attr('href'));
  question.append('<div class="row further-help">Did this answer your question? <span id="further-help-yes">Yes</span> | <span id="further-help-no">No</span></div>');
  question.addClass('selected-faq');
});
```